# Unpermitted parameters In Rails 5 Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I've spent a few hours trying to solve this problem in a Rails 5 project that I have. The issue is that I keep getting:

> Unpermitted parameters: `:item_instance_ids`, `:note_ids`

when I submit a form. I believe that the relationships between the models are wrong. I'm using a polymorphic relationship which is the first time I've used it. I've looked through so many posts on StackOverFlow as well as guides on the web but nothing seems to help me.

Basically, I have an incoming purchases form - like an ordering form and within that form you should be able to add multiple items, like a laptop, keyboard, monitor, to the order => the item instances model.

Anyways, here is my code:

`incoming_purchases.rb`:

```
class IncomingPurchase < ApplicationRecord

  # Relations
  has_many :item_instance, :as => :instance_wrapper
  has_many :notes, :as => :notable
  belongs_to :user


end
```

item_instance.rb

```
class ItemInstance < ApplicationRecord

    # Relations
    belongs_to :instance_wrapper, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :notes, :as => :notable
end
```

`views/incoming_purchases/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@incoming_purchase) do |f| %>

  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <%= f.association :item_instance, as: :check_boxes, :label_method => lambda { |item_instance| "#{item_instance.item.description}" } %>
    <%= f.label(:date_ordered, "Order Date:") %>
    <%= f.text_field(:date_ordered, class: 'form-control-date')  %>
    <%= f.association :user, :label_method => lambda { |user| "#{user.username}" }  %>
    <%= f.input :order_number %>
    <%= f.input :vendor %>
    <%= f.input :po_number %>
    <%= f.input :tax %>
    <%= f.input :shipping %>
    <%= f.association :notes %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-outline-success" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

`incoming_puchases_controller.rb`:

```
class IncomingPurchasesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_incoming_purchase, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @incoming_purchase = IncomingPurchase.new
  end

  def create
    puts '*********************'
    puts params
    puts '*********************'
    puts incoming_purchase_params
    puts '**********************'
    @incoming_purchase = IncomingPurchase.new(incoming_purchase_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @incoming_purchase.save
        format.html { redirect_to @incoming_purchase, notice: 'Incoming purchase was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @incoming_purchase }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @incoming_purchase.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
 
  def set_incoming_purchase
   @incoming_purchase = IncomingPurchase.find(params[:id])
  end

  def incoming_purchase_params
    params.require(:incoming_purchase).permit(:item_instances_id, :date_ordered, :user_id,   :order_number, :vendor, :po_number, :tax, :shipping, :notes_id)
  end

end
```

`schema.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_08_31_200026) do
  create_table "incoming_purchases", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "item_instances_id"
    t.date "date_ordered"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.string "order_number"
    t.string "vendor"
    t.integer "po_number"
    t.decimal "tax", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.decimal "shipping", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.bigint "notes_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["item_instances_id"], name: "index_incoming_purchases_on_item_instances_id"
    t.index ["notes_id"], name: "index_incoming_purchases_on_notes_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_incoming_purchases_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "item_instances", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "inv_number"
    t.string "serial"
    t.integer "po_number"
    t.date "po_date"
    t.date "invoice"
    t.date "date_out"
    t.decimal "cost", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.string "acro"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "item_id"
    t.index ["item_id"], name: "fk_rails_6ea33fd9d0"
  end

  add_foreign_key "incoming_purchases", "item_instances", column: "item_instances_id"

end
```

Oh, on the controller I tried:

```
params.require(:incoming_purchase).permit({ :item_instance_ids => [] }, :date_ordered, :user_id, :order_number, :vendor, :po_number, :tax, :shipping, :notes_id)
```

Again, I think the problem is how the relationship is set up between these two models. Thank you for any help.

I tried changing my permit params to the following:

```
params.require(:incoming_purchase).permit(:item_instances_id, :date_ordered, :user_id, :order_number, :vendor, :po_number, :tax, :shipping, notes_id: [], item_instances_id: [])
```

I was able to add an item but of course item_instances_id did not go through. When the params comes through it looks like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"d3jF73WyKCs69RSCFDvQlh7RyUAg0GQk8m7GKHX6/tt+Ve/1Y1oE5P1UtIMJfCIYS+YL0DwZth9UlDcnyW1uiA==", "incoming_purchase"=>{"item_instance_ids"=>["", "31"], "date_ordered"=>"2020-09-01", "user_id"=>"2", "order_number"=>"1", "vendor"=>"1", "po_number"=>"1", "tax"=>"1", "shipping"=>"1", "note_ids"=>[""]}, "commit"=>"Create Incoming purchase", "controller"=>"incoming_purchases", "action"=>"create"}
```

notice the item_instance_ids however, on the incoming_purchases model it's
item_instances_id notice the position of that s on ids and instances.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the filters you are passing into `permit` are not correct.
It probably needs to be `note_ids: []` as this is a `has_many` relationship.
And when passing nested parameters into `permit` they should be placed at the end. So, you also have to move `item_instance_ids` to the end, either before or after `note_ids: []`.

---

### Edit

You might be better off with a `has_many :though` relationship for tying items to a purchase. I'm not sure how your `Item` model looks like so I kept it simple.

`incoming_purchase.rb`

```rb
class IncomingPurchase < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :purchase_items
  has_many :items, through: :purchase_items
end
```

`purchase_item.rb`

```rb
class PurchaseItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :incoming_purchase
  belongs_to :item
end
```

`item.rb`

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :purchase_items
  has_many :incoming_purchases, through: :purchase_items
end
```

Comment: Yeah that's now working - I added a bit more, at the bottom of my explanation, above. Basically - the Incoming_Purchase model has a property of item_instances_id NOT item_instance_ids

Comment: You might want to check the `has_many` on the `item_instance` declaration in `incoming_purchases.rb`. By convention those relations should be written in plural.

Comment: Yeah - I have changed it to plural - how I currently have it now. Still same error. When I did change it to plural I also changed it to plural in the form as well so f.association :item_instances. The params still keep coming in as:  item_instance_ids

Comment: If I understood your intention right you might be better off with a `has_many :through` relationship. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you Mathias - I was actually thinking that I needed to go down that route as well!